# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class GridSearchCV with abstract methods _run_search

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm working with `spark-sklearn` in PySpark and I tried this code:

```py
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from spark_sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from spark_sklearn.util import createLocalSparkSession

sc = createLocalSparkSession().sparkContext
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svr = svm.SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(sc, svr, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class GridSearchCV with abstract methods _run_search
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
in engine
----> 1 clf = GridSearchCV(sc, svr, parameters)

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class GridSearchCV with abstract methods _run_search
```

Please, can you help me to fix this?

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using (`import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`?